# Basic jQuery Slider image is displaying for a brief moment on the homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an easy fix to this problem where the second image in the slideshow is briefly displaying for a moment on the homepage?

On the following site you will see this image http://www.chesapeakeeyecare.com/site/home_photos/vitality-photo.jpg appear for 1/4 second during the homepage load up.

http://www.chesapeakeeyecare.com/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just hide it with display:none in css and use the $(document).ready() function to remove the attribute

Comment: The current code already sets it to display none in the bjqs css file. There is also an error in the colorbox plugin though. This might be an easy fix but it's non-obvious at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `overflow: hidden !important`

```
ul.bjqs {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```